# WTForms How to use a DecimalField which generates proper field errors on bad input

Tags: python, wtforms, type-coercion

Have a look at this example

```
class MyForm(ForM):
    ...snip...
    quantity = DecimalField(u'Quantity', [NumberRange(1, 8)])
    ...snip...
```

This works nicely if the user is co-operative and enters something that can be coerced to a numeric type.  However, if the user enters, say: "asdf" into this field in the browser then `DecimalField` throws a `Type Error` when I try to render it in the browser.

Here's the relevant parts of the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/path/to/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 894, in render
      return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
    File "/path/to/app/www/templates/submodule/user/submission.html", line 26, in block "submodule_content"
      {{form.quantity}}
    File "/path/to/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 139, in __call__
      return self.widget(self, **kwargs)
    File "/path/to/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wtforms/widgets/core.py", line 123, in __call__
      kwargs['value'] = field._value()
    File "/path/to/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 542, in _value
      return format % self.data
TypeError: a float is required
```

Instead of this behaviour, I'd like the field to have an error added to itself, so that I can still render t.

My current solution involves using a `TextField` instead of a `DecimalField` and providing an `IsNumeric` validator with a call method like:

```
def __call__(self, form, field):
    if field.data:
        try:
            field.data = float(field.data)
        except ValueError as e:
            raise ValidationError(self.message)
```

This works nearly perfectly, and is my current solution, but surely there must be a wtforms-idiomatic way to do this.

Comment: How are you providing the form data to the form (how are you constructing it)? is it being provided using a form-data multi-dict? If so, this error shouldn't be occurring, as the data should never be coerced over to the `.data` property.  This usually happens when people pass raw form data as **kwargs, which are supposed to be only for already-coerced data.

Comment: Yes, this is using the **kwargs style.  There is nothing in the documentation of **kwargs that says they should be already coerced, and with web.py (and maybe other web frameworks), this is how params are returned.  What coercing should be done, and is there a reason that **kwargs are treated differently than a multi-dict?  Mostly, it'd be good if this were explicit in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I had to deal with similar problem. `SelectMultipleField` with `coerce=text_type`(which is a default kwarg) converts input data to `str`/`unicode`. That means it 'coerced' `None` (a value fed into my field when user didn't select anything) into `"None"` - which was huge pain to debug. your question clearly indicates that it was not only me who dove into wtforms internal validation process.

The correct solution I found is, you write a custom subclass of `StringField`(textfield) and override `__call__`, `process_data`, and `process_formdata` methods to suit your needs. `__call__` is for rendering them into html(which should be done by another `widget` callable), `process_data` is usually for getting data from python objects(which means server-side), and `process_formdata` is like `process_data` except it deals with user-submitted forms. or, if you want DRY(don't repeat yourself), you can override `__init__` and make your custom validator default.

edit:

The `DecimalField`'s idiotic code is what causes `TypeError`. Take a look at its `_value()` method, which is used by `DecimalField`'s rendering widget to get X for `<input type="text" ... value=X>`

```
def _value(self):
    if self.raw_data:
        return self.raw_data[0]
    elif self.data is not None:
        if self.places is not None: # <-- this line brings you the pain
            if hasattr(self.data, 'quantize'):
                exp = decimal.Decimal('.1') ** self.places
                if self.rounding is None:
                    quantized = self.data.quantize(exp)
                else:
                    quantized = self.data.quantize(exp, rounding=self.rounding)
                return text_type(quantized)
            else:
                # If for some reason, data is a float or int, then format
                # as we would for floats using string formatting.
                format = '%%0.%df' % self.places
                return format % self.data
        else:
            return text_type(self.data)
    else:
        return ''
```

it checks `field.places` before the type of `field.data` - `field.places` is declared upon field creation, and is merely saying that you want N digits of precision; it does not indicate that you have N digit of `Decimal` as your `fields.data`, but wtforms devs somehow decided that checking `field.places` is enough to assume the field contains corresponding floating point number. (the codes checks whether there is `quantize` attribute on `field.data` but that only works for decimals)

I think you have to write your own subclass of `DecimalField`. here's my attempt at writing a non-idiot version of `DecimalField` :

```
from wtforms.fields.core import DecimalField as _DecimalField

class DecimalField(_DecimalField):
  def _value(self):
    try:
      float(self.data) #check whether you have a 'number'
      return super(DeciamlField, self)._value()
    except (TypeError, ValueError): #self.data is 'None', 'asdf' ...
      return text_type(self.data) if self.data else ''
```

Comment: Surely this is the average case for using a `DecimalField` though?  Yours is a fine solution, but still requires me to write my own wtforms extensions for what I am surprised to find not to be default behaviour.

Comment: can you post your traceback?

Comment: This is good information to have available from google (though, I was more interested in finding something that worked well within the framework).  I filed an issue on the project: https://bitbucket.org/simplecodes/wtforms/issue/146/decimalfield-doesnt-work-in-a-useful-way